# Why didn't Charles follow up with Dwight's client?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-office

In the episode [Broke](https://theoffice.fandom.com/wiki/Broke), Michael learns that his company's low prices are putting him out of business. He calls a client and asks for more money. Presumably, this is the same client that calls Dwight asking to come back. Dwight takes this information to Charles, but Jim intervenes making him look stupid, so Charles kicks him out.

Why didn't Charles followup on Dwight claim?

I know Dwight made Charles look stupid in previous episodes by making nonsensical suggestions.

He could have called the client and speak to them directly.

As David later points out, Michael's demands would end up costing Dunder Mifflin millions of dollars, so it would have been beneficial to call.

Comment: *...but Jim intervenes making him look stupid, so Charles kicks him out.* -- I believe you answered your own question.

Comment: @Charles - Right, but why ignore the information? Jim was irritating Dwight so much that he had to answer him, but Charles should have at least followed up on the information.

Comment: Because Charles already thought that Jim was a joke from where he wore a tux on Charles' first day there, plus Jim getting in trouble during meetings for talking, for Charles thinking Jim is lazy, etc. And then for Dwight, during the MSPC/DM meeting Dwight was yapping on about sabotaging Michael's company with bees, to which Charles eventually responded, "what is wrong with you?" Then, after Jim pushes Dwight talk about the mysteries that he's "cracked", Charles had had enough of both their shenanigans.

Comment: At that point Charles didn't have the patience or nerve to keep up with what either of them were saying, regardless that what Dwight was saying actually had truth to it.

Answer (score 2):

> Right, but why ignore the information? Jim was irritating Dwight so much that he had to answer him, but Charles should have at least followed up on the information.

Jim's interference, more precisely Dwight's list of "cases" he solved, painted Dwight as someone who massively overinflates the importance of the "cases" they solve, which then suggests to Charles that Dwight is massively overinflating the supposed dirt he has on the Michael Scott Paper Company.

Charles is the kind of person who does not waste any effort on what he dislikes or considers beneath him, which is why he never liked Jim and never engaged Jim in an attempt to maybe mitigate his first impressions. Similarly, Dwight has now been painted as not worthy of Charles' attention and is grouped in the same category as Jim.

Charles wasn't right to ignore the suggestion, but him doing so after noticing what an idiot Dwight is (as per Charles' words) fits exactly with Charles' character.

Comment: Not to mention, Charles ends up being just another suck up yo David as later revealed, and thus just another one of the many idiots that are running upper management and corporate, which later causes the company to go bankrupt pending the Sabre merger.....